# Interface Builder only allows one button to be "touchable"

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

I'm making a clone of the classic game simon, the memory matching game.

My (iPad) app will load fine, i tap start, the game screen loads, and only one of my four buttons will respond to touch commands.

To troubleshoot, I tried creating a second unrelated nib and just populating it with four buttons not linked to anything. However, only one of those four buttons would respond to touch! There are no IBActions  being called, nothing. Both the view itself, and all four buttons are touch enabled in the inspector...I'm stumped.

I'm moreso asking if anyone has encountered anything simillar, as I'd rather not burden potential help with app-specific questions if it's avoidable. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying only one button will track at a time, or only one button is responsive at all?

Comment: On further inspection, it seems that the iPad screen is only accepting touches that originate in the top left quadrant, about the size of an iPhone. Must be something to do with originally developing the app for iphone and attempting to upgrade?

Comment: edit: its because the mainwindow.xib that is loading is still the iphone size...any way to change that without making a separate nib?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously more than one button can be touchable and if thry're all enabled in interface builder, something more interesting is going on.

Are you sure that all the buttons are not overlapping (can you add their location and sizes to the question)? And make sure that there are no other views ontop of them?